# Which directories should I backup so that I can restore a system's configuration?

Tags: freebsd, backup

Let's say I decide to nuke my FreeBSD system and do a fresh install. I'd then like to get the system configured the way it was, including some of the scripts I've added. (User data and other valuables are not of concern in this case since they are backed up separately.)

Running `pkg info` before doing so will give me the list of installed packages, so I can easily get that back. But the config is what I'd like to keep.

Which directories should I consider for backup?

```
/etc                # yes
/home               # probably
/root               # yes
/usr/local/etc      # yes
/usr/local/libexec  # yes (contains some of my scripts)
/usr/local/sbin     # yes (contains some of my scripts)
/var                # not sure
```

Comment: it depends on the software you have installed and if you changed their configuration files or not. you should deside what you really need, back it up and reinstall all your extra software on your new installed system replacing your custom configs. your question has no real answer to be honest

Comment: Unless you are installing the exact same version of OS and packages, those directories will include out-of-date system files when you come to restore them. You will need to pick through them and identify the files you've changed anyway, so you may as well do that **before** you nuke the system and only save the files that you have changed or created.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I should have clarified that my aim was to make disaster recovery easier. The base system etc. can always be setup automatically, but usually it's the post-setup configuration that real time is spent on, and I just wanted to have some piece of mind to not lose that stuff.  I have now assembled a list of directories in which I've placed or changed config files and such and am backing those up. Plus a nightly ZFS zroot snapshot.